# PHP Script sending spams and mail.add_x_header not working

Tags: postfix, spam, php5

I've got my server hacked lately by some Php64 malware.
Since then, I have found a lot of PHP files in my /var/www sub-folders.

I am trying to delete each of these or clearing the files when some codes have been added at the top (usually) of the file.

Of course, I understand I should start from scratch with a new wordpress install and with an old safe backup but it would be too much work and my customer would not understand that he has to do again all the pages...

So as I still have a lot spams going out of my server by some PHP scripts, I added the mail.add_x_header to my php.ini in /etc/php5/apache2 on my debian server however, still it doesn't show which script is using the mail command. I have restarted the apache server a few times but no joy.

Any way, the hacker could have protected that function to work or am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Julien.